# Want to eliminate all rows where first entry in one column starts with the letter E

Tags: r, string

```
> Data2<-cbind(c("ETDG","EDJG","METW","TDBT","EITC"),c(1,5,3,4,2))

> Data2

>      [,1]   [,2]
 [1,] "ETDG" "1"
 [2,] "EDJG" "5" 
 [3,] "METW" "3" 
 [4,] "TDBT" "4" 
 [5,] "EITC" "2"
```

I am coding and R and I want to eliminate all of the rows in the above array with entries in the first column that start with the letter E, and I want to do it all at once. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Have u tried `Data2[!grepl("^E", Data2[,1]),]`

Comment: Just did, and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Data2[toupper(substr(Data2[,1],1,1)) != "E",]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Data2 <- Data2[!grepl("^E",Data2[,1]),]
```